# Java servlet async context blocks other requests

Tags: java, servlets

i am try to make system, that takes requests, makes some operations with them (group the same requests, etc.) and then sends response with 1-2 second delay.

So i try to use **AsyncContext** to prevent immediately sending response and send them when i need.

But when i use **AsyncContext** it blocks next responses while the first was not completed. *For the tests i am sending 3 ajax get requests at one time*.

So instead of working with 3 not completed requests, my code wait until 1st request will be completed, then works with 2nd, while 3rd waits until 2nd will be completed.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("GET " + new Date().toString());

    if(!request.getRequestURL().toString().contains("localhost")) {
        try {

            AsyncContext context = request.startAsync();

            context.start(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run () {

                    try {

                        prepare(request, response);
                        addToPool(request, response, context);

                        System.out.println("fin GET " + new Date().toString());

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        }  catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In logs it is looks like this:

```
GET Tue Oct 10 10:16:25
Try combine: false
Req added to waitlist
fin GET Tue Oct 10 10:16:25
Completed

GET Tue Oct 10 10:16:30
Try combine: false
Req added to waitlist
fin GET Tue Oct 10 10:16:30
Completed

GET Tue Oct 10 10:16:35
Try combine: false
Req added to waitlist
fin GET Tue Oct 10 10:16:35
Completed
```

**AsyncContext** shoud act like this or i am doing something wrong?

P.S. 
I was tried use **AsyncContext** without "context.start(new Runnable() {..." and i get the same result.

**UPDATE** - JS code. I am calling **multiReq** on button click event.

```
function multiReq() {
    getCurrAcc();
    getCurrAcc();
    getCurrAcc();
}

function getCurrAcc() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: "http://new59d2023b5d1a4.amocrm.ru.myhost.localarea.local/private/api/v2/json/accounts/current",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {

            alert(JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant part of the javascript

Comment: **Scary Wombat**, done

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in java code or **AsyncContext**.
It's was caused by Chrome cache. Chrome stalls GET requests to get prev req response.
No-cache option resolved this issue.